# add zip file in/out of blob using pdo

Tags: php, pdo, blob

Its first time I'm using BLOB, so I am still trying to figure out some stuff.

first of all, I need to add an additional column into my database where a zip-file will be stored. I did this in phpMyAdmin and set some properties: `Name = file, Type = BLOB, Default = NULL`, is there anything else I need to preset, like `MIME type/Browser transformation/Attributes`?

now I want to add(or better update) the zip-file into an existing column using pdo (only the codes for the update part, pdo connects etc. already existed in my old code and are tested and working):

```
$id = "id_i_got_from_somewhere_else"; //12345
$file_name= "path_to_my_zip_file";  //projectpath/packets/somename.zip, tested, the file exists 

function merge_file($id, $file_name)
{
    $merge_query = "UPDATE packets SET file=:file WHERE id=:id";
    try
    {
        $stmt=$pdo->prepare($merge_query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':file', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}

merge_file($id,$file_name);
```

I can see i.e. a `[BLOB - 53b]` is added to the column. For testing, I click the BLOB and download it as a `.bin-file`, change the extension to `.zip` but cant open it. (bit complicated though, is there a better way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's `file_get_contents()` to do this :

```
function merge_file($id, $file_name)
{
    $merge_query = "UPDATE packets SET file=:file WHERE id=:id";
    try
    {
        $stmt=$pdo->prepare($merge_query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':file', file_get_contents($file_name), PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```